# Logger creating empty logs on Cloudwatch

Tags: logging, .net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch, ilogger

I want to log request and response to and from my .NET Core APIs using AWS .NET Logger and Cloudwatch. My .NET Core app is deployed using Elastic Beanstalk. I have installed the AWS.Logger.AspNetCore package and setup the logger as follows in my StartUp.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) {
    loggerFactory.AddAWSProvider(Configuration.GetAWSLoggingConfigSection());
    //Some more configuration related to the app.
}
```

In my appsettings.json I have the following configuration:

```
"AWS.Logging": {
  "Region": "us-east-2",
  "LogGroup": "MyAppLogs",
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Debug",
    "System": "Information",
    "Microsoft": "Information"
  }
}
```

I have also attached the appropriate policies to my Elastic Beanstalk role to create, update and get log groups and streams. This configuration works properly when working locally (within Visual Studio) but when it is deployed empty logs are created on Cloudwatch.

Comment: Why do you say `NLog` when you are using `AWS.Logger.AspNetCore` ?

Comment: Right, I'll edit my post.

Comment: But if you were using `NLog` then you could activate the NLog InternalLogger and see what is wrong :) https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

Comment: But using NLog shouldn't be the only answer to populate Logs or to get to know the issues, right?

Comment: Believe there is a special setting on the CloudWatch-API where you can enable diagnostic logfile (When not using NLog).